# Instead of (date) or instead of on (date)

Tags: prepositions

A meeting was held on 23/8/17 instead of on 13/08/17

Should there be instead of on or only instead of ?

Comment: I would drop the second on and add a the - and make the date unambiguous: _A meeting was held on the 23rd instead of the 13th of August, 2017_

Comment: The second preposition is optional, although, like @mplungjan said, I would opt to leave it out. Still, this is more of a style issue than a grammatical one.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever one sounds better to the writer's ear is just fine.